# R - what package to scrape data in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: r, microsoft-edge, rselenium

I look into RSelenium, but the supported browsers are only chrome, firefox, phantomjs, and internet explorer. Microsoft Edge is the only browser I have in my laptop, so I'm looking for a package that could help me scrape data in Microsoft Edge without installing another browser. Is there a package I can install to scrape data in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Why do you want to use Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Gie How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835535/r-what-package-to-scrape-data-in-microsoft-edge/69848409#69848409) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the following info:

- You can use [webdriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) for browser automation using Microsoft Edge, and,
- There's a [webdriver R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webdriver/index.html)

So it seems that *may* work. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webdriver/webdriver.pdf)'s the R library `webdriver` documentation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To use Edge driver with **Selenium 3**, the [Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools) package must be installed. In **Selenium 4**, the classes in the tools are fully compatible with the built-in equivalents, so we don't need to install other tools package to use Edge driver with Selenium 4.

But RSelenium uses **Selenium 2**, you can't directly implement EdgeDriver in Selenium before 4. And I don't find any package which can be used with Edge driver in Selenium 2.

To scrape data in Microsoft Edge, I suggest that you refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) and use Selenium 3 or Selenium 4 with other languages, such as C#, Java, Python. This could be more easily and convenient.